Python Datatypes
I am accessing the HousePrices.csv dataset. After assigning the dataframe, I am trying to optimize memory, for that I am changing the data types.
To my surprize I am able to change the date object into datetime. However, the other features like city, country, street, statezip data types are not changing even if I am using correct commands.
Would you help?
How would we change the type of the aforementioned datatypes into 'String' type?
[I am sending you the screenshot of my notebook, ipykernel Python3.]
Changing Data types failed!!!!
I am expecting I will be able to change the data types, so as to ensure when I use the groupby function for mean it wont give me an error. I assume since these features are object datatypes, it is not allowing me to do groupby aggfunction(mean).
Regards
Appreciate you reading and tryna help :)

There is no dedicated datetype for strings in pandas. Anything that's not numerical, datetime or some other specific type is just object. What were you trying to group and mean in the first place, what did you expect to happen, and what happened instead? Ideally, include a minimal reproducible example.

I was grouping the dataframe features by:
df.groupby(['city']).mean()

What I was expecting : that the command will be able to provide me mean of sample observations of numeric data ignoring the categorical data

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Welcome to SO! We understand the first half of your question. String cells dtype will be object so there is no issue there. Then if you would like help on the groupby follow-up, provided this doesn't already exist as a Q&A (it should), please post input sample and code as text. Text is essential for [mre]. In general, see [ask] for why posting picture is strongly de recommended. Ideally your title should summarize the problem. All this advice will help you get answers to future questions.

As said in a previous comment, strings do not have a special data type in pandas and columns with strings are "object" type. You should not have any issues grouping a dataframe by a column of strings, but you will not be able to take the mean as it's not a defined operation for strings.
You could use the "mode" if you want to group by, for example, country and get in the city column the city that appears the most times for that country. However, I suspect you're after grouping by multiple columns. If you want to get the average datetime and price of each country, city, street, and state zip combination, try:
HousePrices.groupby['country','city','street','zipcode'].mean()

